# cambiar validación input text según option elegida en select (Angular 9)

Tags: angular-material, angular9

tengo un formulario reactivo en el que tengo un select y un input text donde debería cambiar la validación según la opción elegida en el select:

```
<select matNativeControl [formControl]="tipodocumento" required>
  <option value="1">D.N.I.</option>
  <option value="2">L.C.</option>
  <option value="3">L.E.</option>
  <option value="4">C.I.</option>
  <option value="5">PASAPORTE</option>
</select>

<mat-label>Nro. Documento</mat-label>
  <input matInput [formControl]="numerodocumento" maxlength="8" required>
<mat-error *ngIf="numerodocumento.invalid">Debe ingresar su Nro. Documento sin puntos ni letras.</mat-error>
```

Al elegir pasaporte el campo input debe dejar tipear alfanumérico, para todas las demás opciones permite tipear solo números.

el código de la validación en el .ts:

```
 tipodocumento = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
 numerodocumento = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]);
```

espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer las validaciones dinámicas en este caso, solo es necesario que escuches los cambios en el `select` y así, poder aplicar la lógica deseada:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario.get("select").valueChanges.subscribe(valor => {
      //Obtenemos el control ya instanciado en el formulario. 
      let objetivoControl = this.formulario.get("objetivo");

      //Quitamos todas las validaciones del control.
      objetivoControl.clearValidators();

      //Agregamos la validacion segun el caso:
      switch (valor) {
        case "numerico":
          //Se agregan de nuevo todas las validaciones que necesites. 
          //En este caso solo agregue la que me parecio oportuna.
          objetivoControl.setValidators([Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]);
          break;
        case "alfanumerico":
          //En el caso del alfanumerico no es necesario aplicar 
          // validaciones. Si necesitas un required aqui lo debes poner. 
          console.log("No ocupamos hacer nada")
          break;
      }

      //Para evitar problemas con la validacion marcamos el campo con 
      // dirty, de esta manera se ejecutan de nuevo las validaciones
      objetivoControl.markAsDirty()
      //Recalculamos el estado del campo para que cambie el estado 
      // del formulario. 
      objetivoControl.updateValueAndValidity()
    });
  }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validaciones-dinamicas-reactive-forms?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias Legna, te pasaste !!!